# Check for non existing rows in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I need a way to determine which rows were deleted from the DB, given a list of IDs of interest.
Something like:

```
var idsOfInterest = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
idsOfInterest.Except(Datacontext.Table.Select(tbl=>tbl.ID)).Dump();
```

How can I do that? What's an optimal LINQ query for it?

EDIT: Is it possible to do it in one step(a single DB query), without querying the existing IDs and then applying Except?

Comment: @RoyDictus I have added a question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own code will do fine. However, there might be a performance problem since you are pulling all IDs from the database, so the following is more efficient.

```
var idsInDatabase =
    from t in DataContext.Table
    where idsOfInterest.Contains(t.ID)
    select t.ID;

var idsDeletes = idsOfInterest.Except(idsInDatabase);
```

**UPDATE:**

From your update I understand, you would like to retrieve all missing IDs from the database, which is quite hard to do, since you want the IDs that don't exist anymore from the database.

If you would try to do this with plain old SQL, you would need either a table that contains a big list of numbers { 0, 1, 2, 3, ... } to join against (since your `Table` does not contain all IDs anymore) or you would create an inner query or table valued function). That might look like this:

```
SELECT  x.id
FROM    (
            SELECT    1 as id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT    2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT    3
            UNION ALL
            SELECT    3) x
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table t ON x.id = t.ID
WHERE   t.ID IS NULL
```

As far as I know, there is no way to translate such construct to LINQ to SQL. The same holds for table valued functions.

So what you can do is join your `Table` with some sort of `Numbers` table, but I personally wouldn't do that, since you're just over complicating things.

Comment: Ok, that's a possible solution, but can it be done in one step? See the edit in the question.

Comment: @jaraics - Why is it important if it is in one step?

Comment: @Ramhound If I had a query that returns just the IDs that I'm interested in, that would be more efficient than retrieving the IDs which are in the list. ...If that's possible... That's the question now

Comment: @jaraics: Please define 'one step' for me. If you mean 'one line of code', this will not be more efficient and even be less readable, which makes it in fact less efficient because of the loss of developer productivity (which costs much more than some possible CPU cycles). If you mean by 'one step' to do the `Except` part in the database; I think this is possible, but much harder to do, since you want to return IDs from the database *that do not exist*. This will -for sure- result in code that is really hard to follow.

Comment: @Steven - By _one step_ i mean one database query.

Answer (score 0):

How bout doing this?

```
        var idsOfInterest = new int[] {1,2,3,4 };

        var table = new int[] {2,3};


        var deletedIDs = from id in idsOfInterest
                         join t in table
                         on id equals t into gj
                         where !gj.Contains(id)
                         select id;
```